# highcharts x-axis minrange and y-axis minrange is not working while zoomtype is xy

Tags: highcharts, highcharts-ng

highcharts x-axis  minRange and y-axis minRange is not working while zoom type is xy . I have attached source code below.

```
Highcharts.chart('container', {
    chart: {
        zoomType: 'xy'
    },
     yAxis: {
        minRange: 50
    },
    xAxis: {
        minRange: 3
    },


    series: [{
        data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4]
    }]
});
```

link : http://jsfiddle.net/o73akv5L/

Comment: I don't see any problem when zooming both min range works fine.

Comment: Could you describe more precisely what do you mean by "not working"? Describe the behaviour you're expecting. Check the API description of minRange here: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.minRange